# Need help in connecting PHP 5.3.0 to Oracle 8i?

Tags: php, oracle, wampserver, oracle8i

I am using wamp 2.0 which has PHP 5.3.0 with `php_oci8.dll` and related files in ext folder.

I have done all the configuration such as installing **Oracle Instant Client 10gR2** and editing php.ini configuration file. Till now, everything is good.

Here is the screenshot of oci8 configuation details from `index.php` run via localhost.

click here: [OCI8 details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYbNj.png)

And this is the connection string I am using to connect PHP to Oracle:

```
<?php
$dvlp = '(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.3.155)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = DVLP))
  )' ;
$odbc = ocilogon ('work', 'work', $dvlp) 
or die( "Could not connect to Oracle database!") 
or die (ocierror());
?>
```

But it is throwing a connection error as follows:

`Warning: ocilogon() [function.ocilogon]: ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported. in C:\wamp\www\new.php on line 6
Could not connect to Oracle database!`

I have tried everything I could think of and searched a lot regarding this but all in vein. Maybe, the problem is with the compatibility between the php, oci8 and the instant client 10gr2, but no idea.

PS: I am using Windows Server 2003 for a small project.

Thanks!

Comment: So your client is 10g and your server is 8i?  Make some research on Oracle documentation, but I doubt this is a supported configuration.  Down version your client or up version your server (probably simpler to use 8i client).

Comment: Maybe, but it is specified in php.ini to use instant client 10gr2 with php_oci8.dll. 
And, the compatibility chart in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e23633/intro.htm#UPGRD12472   confuses me.

Comment: And another problem is I can't seem to find the instant client 9i version if, though compatible with oracle 8i.

Comment: haha, confusing documentation at Oracle is how they stay in business (selling professional services!).  The ORA-03134 error is pretty clear.  But finding Oracle 8i client might be a challenge, this version has been out of service for many years...

Comment: That's why I rarely refer their documentations. And according to me, or what I have learnt from some sources on web, the oracle brought out the concept of Instant Client from 10g.

Is there any way to bypass this? if no, I will have to try alternate ways.

Comment: Why use these super old version of everything?  Can't you export the data and upgrade to something more recent?

Comment: The problem is my workplace is using this. They are upgrading now, but will take time.

Comment: Even version 10g is out of support for many years.

Comment: Oracle 8i is not supported anymore along with oracle 9i and 10g, oracle is not distributing any of these release anymore, I wonder why you still use oracle 8i today. Also you will need the full version of the 8i database, I think a 10g client will only connect to a 8.1.7.4 database but no earlier versions.

Comment: @Cyrille, then the best option is to switch to MYSQL. Need to learn how to migrate from Oracle 8i to MYSQL.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit currently I am using Oracle 11g version at home learning about 12c.

Comment: Is that a new project? if you plan on migrating your database why not use the last release Oracle 12c?